# Angular: form validation causing an error

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm basing this exercise on this: [forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#template1). That example tells us to use the `#name` property and assign it to "name". However, that property is already used to retrieve my data on submitting the form (as seen on the last rule). I receive an error when attempting to define my own name:

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I'm a bit confused as to the workings of this.

```html
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName">Name</label>
        <input #name type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" required minlength="2" maxlength="20"
        name="companyName" [(ngModel)]="company.name" #companyName="ngModel">

        <div *ngIf="companyName.errors && (companyName.dirty || companyName.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div [hidden]="!companyName.errors.required">Name is required</div>
            <div [hidden]="!companyName.errors.minlength"> Name must be at least 2 characters long.</div>
            <div [hidden]="!companyName.errors.maxlength">Name cannot be more than 20 characters long.</div>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="add(name.value, street.value, number.value, zipCode.value, city.value, iban.value, telephone.value)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My Company object:

```html
export class Company {
    name: string;
    street: string;
    number: string;
    zipCode: string;
    city: string;
    iban: string;
    telephone: string;

    constructor(name: string, street: string, number: string, zipCode: string, city: string, iban: string, telephone: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.street = street;
        this.number = number;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.city = city;
        this.iban = iban;
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the ```#name```. You have already ```#companyName``` which you can use in submit by ```companyName.value```. By the way, isn't the error about ```[(ngModel)]="company.name"```? Show us the ```company``` object.

Comment: elzoy, I have added my company object to my question. No idea why the colors aren't showing up, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `#name` and use the `companyName.value` instead.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html